# Every time the battery of my laptop dies, the timedatectl gets messed up upon restart

Tags: arch-linux

The result, I have to fix the date and time first to be able to connect to the internet.

This is really annoying. I know letting the computer's battery run out is bad.

It happens, and then I encounter this problem.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Use timedatectl with NTP (Network Time Protocol).`timedatectl set-ntp true` or

Comment: replace the CMOS battery

Comment: Change the coin shaped battery of the Real Time Clock on your motherboard. Also read `man hwclock`.